# Drupal + Moodle SingleSignOn logout issues

Tags: 7, authentication-authorization, cookies

**Does anyone know how to set cookie_domain to use an IP-Address and not a domain name?**

I recently put together a SSO solution between Drupal and Moodle. Drupal is acting as the users repository with Moodle as a subdirectory.

To get the sso working I'm using the [moodle-sso](https://www.drupal.org/project/moodle_sso) module to good effect.

**The only problem is that logging out of moodle does not log a user out of drupal.**

After much googling, I found articles indicating cookies are the key to solving this problem.

I attempted following moodle-sso cookie_domain instructions but then I can't log into my site anymore because I access my dev site via IP address and not a domain name.

I set cookie_domain as follows: `$cookie_domain = 'http://128.79.128.44/drupal-site';`

The project structure is `http://128.79.128.44/drupal-site/moodle`.

Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

I added the following data to my */etc/hosts* file on my Linode server:

`128.79.128.44/drupal-site/ dev.drupalsite.com`.

When I visit *dev.drupalsite.com* I receive the following error:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

**Clearly, *dev.drupalsite.com* is not a globally recognised URL but how do I use it to access my website on a LIVE Linode server?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$cookie_domain` can only be set to a domain that you want the `Set-Cookie` header to specify. This doesn't include protocol or path, just the domain with a leading dot (e.g. ".example.com"). If you leave `$cookie_domain` commented out, the browser will default to the domain that you requested it on.

If you need to access a Drupal site by IP when its cookie is set to another domain, you can create a subdomain on your hosts file that maps to the IP.

```
128.79.128.44 dev.example.com
```

Once that's saved to your hosts file, you should be able to browse to http://dev.example.com/ and have your web browser send the relevant cookies (assuming the cookies of domain are set to "example.com").

Comment: Hey Shawn, thank you so much. I added a quick update to my question.

Comment: Hosts files map a domain to an IP address.  You can't map a path in it. You still have to request the site in its subdir.